# Creating and using dictionaries from file with python

Tags: python

Pretty new to python and trying to complete a project which will help with work.

I'm using a csv document which has 3 columns of data, I want python to go into the file sort the ssc and match the relevant tprs (as some of these will have 2 tprs) to each ssc with the rates. It looks like this.

```
ssc,tpr,rate    
0149,01394,OffPeak    
0150,00042,Day    
0150,00207,Night    
0151,00043,Day    
0151,00210,OffPeak    
0152,00045,Day    
0152,00211,Night    
0153,00046,Day
```

Part of my program will search this document after requesting an input for an ssc to make sure it exists then I want it to grab that `ssc`, `tpr` and rate and use them in a separate dictionary list or w/e so I can use them to fill in other parts of my program.

My first problem is looking to be just going through the file and sorting everything as I would rather have one ssc with `tpr1 + rate` and `tpr2 + rate` for example

```
ssc  tpr1  rate  tpr2  rate    
0151 00043 Day  00210 Offpeak
```

or if there is just one tpr and rate

```
ssc   tpr1  rate    
0393  00001 UnrestrictedSingle
```

Then I need python to adjust another part of my program by adding an extra line, depending on how many tprs there are. so if there's only 1 then just add one but if there are 4 then It will need to add 4 lines for the tprs

That looks like

```
ZPI||    
ZIN||||||    
ISD||    
EAH||    
EAD|tpr1||    
EAD|tpr2||    
REG|||    
PSC||countofrates|ssc|    
IMC|||    
GSP|||    
IES|||    
ZPT|||||
```

the line starting EAD is the line that needs to be added depending on how many `tprs` there are and the `countofrates` needs to change depending on if there are 1 or 2

Any help with this would be massively appreciated! Happy to share anything extra if needed

Thanks!

p.s

This is everything I have so far still in its simple form as I cant use my file to fill in sections that I want it too.

```py
fname = open('tprsheettidy.txt')
SSClist = list()              
for line in fname:  
    num = line.split()
    ssc = num  
    for ssc in num:
        if ssc in SSClist : continue                             
    SSC = num[0] 
    SSClist.append(SSC)  
 




print("""What flow would you like to make? D0019 and D0086""")

Dflow = input("> ")
prompt = '> '




if Dflow == "D0019 and D0086":
    print("please enter the SSC")
    SSC = input ("> ")
    if SSC in SSClist:
        print(SSC,"is a valid SSC")

        if SSC == "0393":
            print(f"What is the current time and date?")
            TAD = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the MPAN?")
            MPAN = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the supply start date")
            REGI = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the EAC?")
            EAC = input(prompt)
            print(f"Please enter the GPS code")
            GSP = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the Meter Serial Number?")
            MSN = input(prompt)
            print(f"Please enter 'c' for customer read or 'd' for an estimated read")
            READTYPE = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the REG ID?")
            REGID1 = input(prompt)
            print(f"Please enter the meter reading")
            METERREADING1 = input(prompt)
            print(f"""ZHV|000000|D0119001|X|PSUK|D|LBSL|{TAD}||||OPER|
ZPI|652|   
ZIN|47862|NH09|{MPAN}|||
ISD|{REGI}|
EAH|{REGI}| 
EAD|00001|{EAC}|
REG|{REGI}|PSUK|
PSC|20170727|1|0393|
IMC|20200507|A|
GSP|19960401|{GSP}|
IES|20200507|E|
ZPT|000000|10|1|{TAD}|

ZHV|000000|D0086002|X||D||{TAD}||||OPER|
196|{MPAN}|V|
197|{MSN}|{READTYPE}|
198|{REGID1}|{REGI}000000|{METERREADING1}||T|N|
ZPT|000000|3||1|{TAD}|
""")
        elif SSC == "0151":
            print(f"What is the current time and date?")
            TAD = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the MPAN?")
            MPAN = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the supply start date")
            REGI = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the EAC?")
            EAC = input(prompt)
            EACDAY = (0.66 * float(EAC))
            EACNIGHT = (0.33 * float(EAC))
            print(f"Please enter the GPS code")
            GSP = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the Meter Serial Number?")
            MSN = input(prompt)
            print(f"Please enter 'c' for customer read or 'd' for an estimated read")
            READTYPE = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the first REG ID?")
            REGID1 = input(prompt)
            print(f"What is the second REG ID?")
            REGID2 = input(prompt)
            print(f"Please enter the meter reading for REGID {REGID1}")
            METERREADING1 = input(prompt)
            print(f"Please enter the meter reading for REGID {REGID2}")
            METERREADING2 = input(prompt)
            print(f"""ZHV|000000|D0119001|X|PSUK|D|LBSL|{TAD}||||OPER|
ZPI|652|   
ZIN|47862|NH09|{MPAN}|||
ISD|{REGI}|
EAH|{REGI}| 
EAD|00043|{EACDAY}|
EAD|00210|{EACNIGHT}|
REG|{REGI}||
PSC|20170727|1|0393|
IMC|20200507|A|
GSP|19960401|{GSP}|
IES|20200507|E|
ZPT|000000|10|1|{TAD}|

ZHV|000000|D0086002|X||D||{TAD}||||OPER|
196|{MPAN}|V|
197|{MSN}|{READTYPE}|
198|{REGID1}|{REGI}000000|{METERREADING1}||T|N|
198|{REGID2}|{REGI}000000|{METERREADING2}||T|N|
ZPT|000000|3||1|{TAD}|
""")
```

this only works for two specific sscs being 0393 and 0151 but as there are many many more in the file I want to be able to populate these into this program.

Thanks again

Comment: do you have any code to show?

Comment: It is unclear to me where the start of the strings in the second part is coming from (like `ZP`, `ZIN`, ...) and what "adding an extra line" means? Also, from what you have written it looks like every second line in your csv file is empty?

Comment: sorry I'm just getting used to how to format this properly. I hope what ive added and changes helps a bit. Im still new to this and I might not be explaining what im trying to do very well...

Comment: Did you know there is a `csv` module in the standard library? Did you try reading its documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionaries from a CSV file easily using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: mydata = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', dtype=str)

In [3]: myssc = mydata.loc[mydata['ssc'] == '0151', :]

In [4]: print(f'Number of tprs: {myssc.shape[0]}')
Number of tprs: 2

In [6]: mydict = myssc.loc[:, ['tpr', 'rate']].to_dict()

In [7]: mydict
Out[7]: {'tpr': {3: '00043', 4: '00210'}, 'rate': {3: 'Day', 4: 'OffPeak'}}

In [8]: mydict = myssc.loc[:, ['tpr', 'rate']].to_dict('records')

In [9]: mydict
Out[9]: [{'tpr': '00043', 'rate': 'Day'}, {'tpr': '00210', 'rate': 'OffPeak'}]
```

The `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()` method has [many options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for laying out the dicts in different ways depending on your needs.

Comment: Amazing! Not used pandas im gonna have to go have a play and see what I can make it do.

Thank you very much for your reply definitely a step closer